# Adding scripting security to an application

Tags: java, security, architecture, groovy, scripting

Let's say I have an existing application written in Java which I wish to add scripting support to. This is fairly trivial with Groovy (and just as trivial in .Net with any of the Iron range of dynamic languages).

As trivial as adding the support is, it raises a whole host of questions about script execution and security - and how to implement that security.

Has anyone come across any interesting articles/papers or have any insights into this that they'd like to share? In particular I'd be very interested in architectural things like execution contexts, script authentication, script signing and things along those lines... you know, the kind of stuff that prevents users from running arbitrary scripts they just happened to download which managed to screw up their entire application, whilst still allowing scripts to be useful and flexible.

**Quick Edit**

I've mentioned signing and authentication as different entities because I see them as different aspects of security.

For example, as the developer/supplier of the application I distribute a signed script. This script is legitimately "data destructive" by design. Such as it's nature, it should only be run by administrators and therefore the vast majority of users/system processes should not be able to run it. This being the case it seems to me that some sort of security/authentication context is required based on the actions the script performs and who is running that script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look at the documentation on security:
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Security
Basically, you can use the usual Java Security Manager.

And beyond this, there's a sample application showing how you can introspect the code by analyzing its AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) at compile-time, so that you can allow / disallow certain code constructs, etc. Here's an example of an arithmetic shell showing this in action:
http://svn.groovy.codehaus.org/browse/groovy/trunk/groovy/groovy-core/src/examples/groovyShell

Answer (score 2):

> script signing

Conceptually, that's just reaching into your cryptographic toolbox and using the tools that exist.  Have people sign their code, validate the signatures on download, and check that the originator of the signature is trusted.

The hard(er) question is what makes people worthy of trust, and who gets to choose that.  Unless your users are techies, they don't want to think about that, and so they won't set good policy.  On the other hand, you'll probably *have* to let the users introduce trust [unless you want to go for an iPhone AppStore-style walled garden, which it doesn't sound like].

> script authentication

How's this different from signing?  Or, is your question just that: "what are the concepts that I should be thinking about here"?

The real question is of course: what do you want your users to be secured against?  Is it only in-transit modification, or do you also want to make guarantees about the behavior of the scripts?  Some examples might be: scripts can't access the file system, scripts can only access a particular subtree of the file system, scripts can't access the network, etc.

I think it might be possible [with a modest amount of work] to provide some guarantees about how scripts access the outside world if they were done in haskell and the IO monad was broken into smaller pieces.  Or, possibly, if you had the scripts run in their own opaque monad with access to a limited part of IO.  Be sure to remove access to unsafe functions.

You may also want to look at the considerations that went into the Java (applet) security model.

I hope this gives you something to think about.

Comment: i think reusing the java applet security model looks like a good start.